# How to get items so that it is not null (useEffect)?

Tags: reactjs

How to get items so that it is not null? I'm trying to write the values ​​that I get through useEffect to sidebat -> items, but I get null, in general, is it mandatory to use 2 useEffect? Maybe you can somehow do it through one, so as not to duplicate the code?

```
const [sidebarItemsLeagues, setSidebarItemsLeagues] = useState(null);
const [sidebarItemsCountries, setSidebarItemsCountries] = useState(null);

const [sidebars] = useState({
    leagues: {
        title: "TITLE 1", 
        items: sidebarItemsLeagues // null...
    },
    countries: {
        title: "TITLE 2",
        items: sidebarItemsCountries // null...
    }
});

useEffect(() => {
    api.getTestLeagues()
    .then(data => setSidebarItemsLeagues(data)); // for items 1 (not null)
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    api.getTestCountries()
    .then(data => setSidebarItemsCountries(data)); // for items 2 (not null)
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

If `sidebars` is a computed value, then don't create a state variable for it. By using `useState` you specify only what it's *initial* value is, and then any updates need to be done by calling `setSidebars`, which you never do.

```
const sidebars = {
    leagues: {
        title: "TITLE 1", 
        items: sidebarItemsLeagues
    },
    countries: {
        title: "TITLE 2",
        items: sidebarItemsCountries
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

2 `useEffect` is not mandatory, you can do both fetches **one by one** ... but you probably **want** to run them **in parralel**, not sequentially.

You can block rendering with empty data by

```
<>
  {sidebarItemsLeagues && sidebarItemsCountries && ( 
    <LeaguesList data={sidebarItemsLeagues} />
    <Countries data={sidebarItemsCountries} />
  )}
</>
```